How to get the classId of an item from the Steam API with an inspect link values?
I want to retreive the float value and paint seed of items on the steam market in Python. The items are from counter strike 2.
I managed to get the inspect link of the items listed on the market but now, apparently, I need a classId to get those float and paint seed values. The problem is I can't find a way to get this classId
Also, it seems that there is a difference to retrieve the classId if the inspect link contains an M rather than an S.
Any help would be much appreciated !

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A market listing has three parts as far as I know, M A D, with M being the listing ID and A being the assetid (D always provided)
An example of a non-populated (can be found in regular inventory response)
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D910550409944203216
And one populated:
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M5231585837963410495A36933563414D14870894776049808240
This populated one of course returns the float and other values you're looking for (in this case 0.31265467405319214), I utilized CSInventoryAPI.com for that.
Can you share a little more about the data returned about each marketplace item? That would make it easier to help : )
